# FreeMarker conditional with spaces in value

Tags: conditional-statements, freemarker

I have a conditional if, which takes a field, and evaluate its value against a fixed string. In the case the string which is evaluated contains an string the validation does not return the correct value, only works with value without spaces
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id41g.png)

as you can see there is data on those variables and the conditional works with data without spaces or other data that is created, but not with the variables with yellow arrow.

Im missing something?, an additional conversion or something? This is done with FreeMarker v 2.3.20.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image it should work, so I suspect there's some invisible character there. For example, there can be a trailing space that you don't see because there's nothing directly after the printed value, or maybe the space between the two words is not really a space (0x20) but an nbsp (0xA0) character. Try `${principal.name?url}` to see those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for some reason the url command doesnt show anything http://imgur.com/x6pSa7E
any other idea to see those possible hidden characters (I used html tag also)

Comment: HTML doesn't do that. It's very weird that `?url` shows nothing. Maybe it had a bug in that very old FreeMarker version when `url_encoding_charset` is not set, so try `?url('utf-8')` (and BTW, upgrade FreeMarker). Also, now you show `BeneficaryCompany` for the HTML version... typo?

Comment: Hi, with ?url('utf-8') it worked, and shows: Beneficiary%26nbsp%3BCompany

http://imgur.com/a/4xfGZ

anyway doing the comparison whit that doesnt work

Comment: So then the name doesn't even contain a hidden nbsp, but a HTML entity reference, `&nbsp;`. I guess you have checked the output in a browser and that's why you haven't seen that (use the source view next time). And of course then the comparison doesn't work. If you are going to hard code names into the template, then something has to ensure that they are stored properly on the other side as well. Or you do `principal.name?replace('&nbsp;', ' ') == ...`, but that's really just a hack, not the real solution.

Comment: then, wich could be the real solution?, 

-upgrading FreeMarker version, 

- and using a directive on the template (I tried using `setDefaultEncoding, setURLEscapingCharset, setOutputEncoding, setWhitespaceStripping` with no luck.)

- adding tags as mentioned here [link](https://watchitlater.com/blog/2011/10/default-html-escape-using-freemarker/)  (also no luck)

-or, is this a bug?


the replace worked `[#if principal.name?replace('&nbsp;', ' ')=="Beneficiary Company"] 
si es este Beneficiario reemplazando
[/#if]` .. but as you said that doesnt seem to be the best way

Comment: `?url` was only used for debugging, you don't need it here otherwise. (It's very, very strange that it prints nothing for you; I have tried with 2.3.20, and here it works correctly. No idea how you do it...) "Default HTML-escape" is also irrelevant here (and that article is outdated; escaping by default is core feature now), as is upgrading FreeMarker (but it's highly recommended regardless). Neither of these will make strings that are indeed different magically equal. You are comparing values that seem to be rather fragile. That's the real problem. Why's that `&nbsp;` there?